# Ubuntu 20.04 stuck in reset system loop

Tags: boot, acer

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04.03LTS from a dvd on an Acer Aspire ES1-S31 laptop but following the removal of the setup dvd and pressing enter as prompted the Acer logo is displayed then the message "system reset" appears in the top left hand corner of the screen and then this sequence continues to reappear in a continuous loop. Is there a way to break the loop and enter Ubuntu?(there is no other O/S on the computer).

Comment: is this a problem with your bios trying to restore a previous windows install.

Answer (score 2):

Credit to [@Hasumashi's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1390943/1165986) for pointing me in the right direction.  What worked for me on ThinkPad X1 Yoga was to:

- Disable “Boot Order Lock” in BIOS
- Reboot
- “Reset System” is displayed
- Computer reboots
- Reenable “Boot Order Lock” in BIOS.

I didn’t have to run `sudo efibootmgr …`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04.3 on ThinkPad E590 laptop using whole disk, so I'm not sure if it will work for your Acer. But it turned out when installing Ubuntu it didn't set EFI menu entry. I tried using `efibootmgr` to manually add entry for grub but changes didn't persist on reboot.

The problem was that I had **"Boot order Lock"** option enabled in UEFI. So to resolve the issue disable it, boot to live CD and either reinstall grub or add EFI entry using `efibootmgr`:

```
sudo efibootmgr -c -d /dev/nvme0n1p1 -L Ubuntu -l /EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
```

replacing `/dev/nvme0n1p1` with the EFI ESP partition.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Lenovo Ideapad 1-14IGL05 with Intel Pentium Silver N5030 (such as mine) and you are stuck in bootloop with text "reset system" after installing Linux (Ubuntu, in my case), just disable Intel Platform Trust Technology in UEFI.

**To do that:**

1. Switch off your laptop.
2. Press and keep pressing F2 continuously
3. While pressing F2, power on your laptop. The laptop should enter UEFI (BIOS). (If this doesn't work, keep F2 pressed all the time and switch on your laptop).
4. In the UEFI go to Security tab.
5. Change "Intel Platform Trust Technology" to "disabled".
6. That's it. Your laptop should now start to operate normally - it should be out of the bootloop.